# Javascript notification plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications

I'm developing a web 2.0 app using HTML/Javascript and Java for server side.

My app manage a lot of notifications per-user and I would add a simple popup with unread number after a user click (like facebook) that shows the latest 10 notification (I've just implemented logic within server side).

Is there any graphic plugins (e.g. by jQuery) that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of Notify.js - http://notifyjs.com. It depends on jQuery at the moment but I do plan to remove the dependency in future. Post any questions you have about it here https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/issues

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I've written, it has no dependencies and is very lightweight: http://shaundon.github.io/simple-notifications/